# Java abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I want to construct an abstract class Animal, which is inherited by several species for example Hawk. I did the following:

```
abstract public class Animal {

      private String name;
      abstract String sound();
      abstract String movement();
      public void set_name(String s){
        name=s;
      }
      public String get_name(){
        return name;
      }
    }
    public Hawk extends Animal{
      public String sound(){
       return "Shriek" ;
      } 
      public String movement(){
       return "Fly" ;
      }
```

However, the compiler keeps telling me duplicate method sound() and movement() found in Animal, why would this happen? I m just trying to implement this.

Comment: Am I misreading the code, or is `Hawk` nested inside `Animal`? Also, warnings or error messages?

Comment: use `@Override`

Comment: Looks like you're missing `class` in front of `Hawk`.

Comment: a public class has to be in its own file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
public Hawk extends Animal
```

to

```
class Hawk extends Animal
```

You can only have one public class in a .java file.  Plus you forgot the "class" keyword.

Comment: Great!  If so, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two corrections need to be made in your code.

**1-**

Hawk is a class,so declare Hawk as `public class Hawk extends Animal`

**2-**

Two public classes can't be in same .java file.

So,the correct code is as follows:-

```
abstract  class Animal {
      private String name;
      abstract String sound();
      abstract String movement();
      public void set_name(String s){
        name=s;
      }
      public String get_name(){
        return name;
      }
    }

    public  class Hawk extends Animal{
      public String sound(){
       return "Shriek" ;
      } 
      public String movement(){
       return "Fly" ;
      }
    }
```

Comment: when declared as an inner class like this, the only way a `Hawk` can exist is with an outer `Animal` - which isn't what you want. You have to make Hawk static to avoid that coupling

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code!  No two public classes together!

```
abstract class Animal {
      private String name;
      abstract String sound();
      abstract String movement();
      public void set_name(String s){
        name=s;
      }
      public String get_name(){
        return name;
      }
    }

    public class Hawk extends Animal{
        @override
      public String sound(){
       return "Shriek" ;
      } 
         @override
      public String movement(){
       return "Fly" ;
      }
    }
```